# C# search values within range

Tags: c#, linq

I have an array of complex types, let's call it `Point` (see below), and I want to find all points that are within a given range of X values `[minX, maxX]`. I need to do this search millions of times. How can I do this the fastest way?

```
public class Point {
    public double X { get; set; };
    public double Y { get; set; };
}

Point[] data;
```

I could do the search simply with `data.Where(c => c.X > minX && c.x < maxX)` but this is too slow.
Note that I can sort the array by `X` with `data.sort(c => c.X)` apriori so theoretically I could return a chunk starting from the first element greater than `minX` and stoping at the first element greater than `maxX`. How can I do this?

Comment: Part of the reason it's going slowly is because iterating through millions of records is a slow process.  You may want to consider PLINQ for a performance increase.    That's all I can think of at the moment, since you're not doing a particularly expensive calculation. 


  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997399(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: if you're not limited to `Array`, consider a [range trie](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8434264/1132334) over `X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try sorting the list first and then do a binary search on the list to find the index of min and max

Then you can do

```
.Skip(minIndex).Take(maxIndex - minIndex + 1)
```

Or, if you want it to be simple rather than speed then

```
.SkipWhile(x=>x <= minX).TakeWhile(x=>x < maxX)
```

Comment: Can you exemplify how I do the BInarySearch on the list? Sorry, newbye to C# here

Comment: @manatttta https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm. Its simple, only 4 conditions.

Comment: There's a `BinarySearch` methon in `List`. Isn't this suitable?

Comment: Nope, the method requires you to know the element you are searching for before hand and I assume you don't.